# Syntax: using IF statement in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write an `If` statement that will satisfy the condition with just using one word. For example:

```
if sheet1.cells(1,1)="a quick brown fox" then
end if
```

What I want to happen is even if there's only the word `"quick"`, the condition would be satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `InStr()` function to test a string for a substring:

```
If InStr(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), "quick") > 0 Then
    ' Cell contains the string "quick"
End If
```

For a case-insensitive comparison, you must supply all four possible arguments to the function:

```
If InStr(1, Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), "quick", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    ' Cell contains the string "quick" or "QUICK" or any combination of upper/lowercase
End If
```

As @AndyG mentions in the comments below, you can also use the `Like` operator with wildcards to test if a string contains a substring:

```
If Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) Like "*quick*" Then          ' Case-sensitive
-or-
If LCase$(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) Like "*quick*" Then  ' Case-insensitive
```

Note that these methods would also match `"quickly"` and other words containing the string `"quick"`. If you want to get more specific, a regex may work better. Add a reference to the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` library and you can use the following:

```
Dim re As New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = False       ' Up to you
re.Pattern = "\bquick\b"    ' Match the word "quick"

If re.Test(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) Then
    ' Cell contains the word "quick"
End If
```

Comment: Well basically i want to copy all cells in a cell range that has, for example, word "fox" in it. Cant I just use the * symbol? I forget what its called when you do it with the *.

Comment: The _word_ `"fox"` or the _string_ `"fox"`? If you want to look for the word only, use the regex example shown above but replace `\bquick\b` with `\bfox\b`.

Comment: For the * you can use `Cells(1,1) Like "*quick*"`

Comment: I have a code in the same project but i used the * witg countif. What it does is basically, it counts all the cells with, for example, "*ABC*". And the syntax I used is the same way, "*ABC*"

Comment: Again, if you want to just match the _string_, you can use `InStr()` to test that the string appears within the cell. Or you can use what @AndyG has shown, but that's case-sensitive.

Comment: @AndyG so i need to include "Like" in that line to make it work? I tried doing that without the word Like in it and it didnt work. Sorry i cant type lines or words in code, im on my mobile right now.

Comment: Yes, you need the word Like. @Bond has already answered your question. If it is not the answer you are looking for then you need to clarify your question. What's wrong with InStr or regex?

Comment: @AndyG I see. I just thought that using * is simpler but if it has the downside of being case-sensitive then I'll use IntStr and regex. Thank you both for all your help :)

Comment: You could use `UCase(Cells(1,1)) Like "*QUICK*"` to make it case-insensitve but, personally, I'd be happy to use InStr.

Comment: @AndyG I've edited the answer to include your suggestions among the available options. Thanks for the input.